# I set Obstacle Avoidance - Radius of NavMesh in Unity, and the unit refuse to move?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, navmesh

[image: The editor UI]

As this image show, when I set Obstacle Avoidance - Radius to 4.5 and lower, the unit will refuse to move (it means it can't find the path?), but if I set it 5.0 or higher, all will work well. I've set the radius before I bake the NavMesh, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've solved this question.
In my scene, I command unit whitch transform.position is (5, -13, 10) find path and go to (0, 0, 0) in a plane which position.y is -13. In this case, the path-finding can only work well when the radius is larger than a threshold, but cannot work while the radius is too small.
I don't understand how can it be, but anyway, If I command it to the right position, (0, -13, 0), all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

[You should keep these proportions balanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oO2z.png)

1-This radius is the collider boundaries of the agent

2-You can increase agents acceleration value, that is will calculate its route more accurately

3-When you bake area, give same radius to bake option